# Where is the statusbar in Firefox 4+? How do I get it back?

Tags: firefox, plugins, statusbar

Since version 4.0b7pre, there is no more statusbar in Firefox, which has been replaced by the new add-ons bar.

The main problem is that a lot of users like me are missing some valuable information that was displayed in the statusbar on previous versions. For instance, when  hovering a link the url is now displayed in the address bar and you can't see the entire address. Other information like which servers are being contacted when you load a page are no longer displayed.

Answer (score 2):

For that, you need an addon.
[This](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/status-4-evar/) one precisely.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to show/hide the status bar in Firefox.